# Base addresses not the same

Tags: reverse-engineering, ollydbg, ida

When I load up an executable in IDA pro and OllyDbg, the addresses of the same instructions start up at different locations. This could be because they are different base addresses. I would like the executables use the same base address; how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you loading it with ollydbg? Because if you attach to a running process, the OS can freely reallocate it, if you however start the process through olly, it'll try load it at its preferred base address(only the binary you load, its dependancies are free to be relocated, if its a dll you'll need to use ollys loaddll.exe), else it'll virtualize and fake the addresses. IDA should be able to do the same. If the modules don't have a preferred base address you can use LordPE or MSVC's rebase.exe it give it a preferred base address.